# Modulus not working correctly with Math.log10(n)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, modulo, logarithm

`Math.log10(8)/Math.log10(2)` // this is equal to exactly 3

However, when using the modulo operator, sth doesn't add up!

`Math.log10(8)%Math.log10(2)` //this is not equal to zero(0).

I was expecting the modulo operator to equal to zero

Please explain this phenomenon and a way to find reminders for natural logs. Thanks

Comment: `Math.log10(8)/Math.log10(2)` mathematically means a base-2 log of 8, which is exactly 3 because 2^3=8. It'd also equal 3 if you replaced both log10() occurrences with regular log() or log of any other base. I have no idea what you're trying to achieve with `Math.log10(8)%Math.log10(2)`, that answer will be gibberish.

Comment: I am trying to solve a puzzle whereby yu are supposed to test whether a given number 'n' is a power of 2. So far, using Bitwise gives the best BigO notation. I was trying to beat that using simple logs. From maths:
- if 2^x = n  ; then :
  xlog2 = logn 
; dividing both sides by log2 will give whole number x; i.e.
x = logn/log2
Therefore, there will be no remainder. This was the reason for using modulo operator.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. It's the precison error that means if the result is off by a very very tiny amount, you'll get either slightly more than zero or slighly less than `Math.log10(2)` if you use the `%` operator. What you need to do is check whether the result is an integer, which you can do using `Math.log10(8)/Math.log10(2)%1===0`. Due to precision errors, you may need to instead write something like`Math.log10(8)/Math.log10(2)%1<0.000000000001`.

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering [rounding error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) which inherently happens in floating point arithmetic.

`Math.log10(8)` in JavaScript evaluates to `0.9030899869919435`.

On [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=log10%288%29) `log10(8)` is evaluated to `0.9030899869919435856412166841734790803045696443863256239312823833`.

These are different numbers. Neither is wrong, but one is more precise than the other.

When doing math with imprecise decimal approximations of numbers like you are here, you will get imprecise results. This is especially pronounced when you try do modulo operations on such imprecise approximations. For example `8 % 2` and `8 % 2.000000001` give very different results. The former is `0` and the latter is just shy of `2`.

You can use a library like [math.js](https://mathjs.org/) which can avoid floating point math in these sorts of calculations, and where `math.mod(math.log(8, 10), math.log(2, 10))` does indeed evaluate to 0.